# How transform a value into a html element in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, html, web, processing, p5.js

I’m trying to make a single web page with p5.js, but at some moment I create an input and the value of the input I want to transform into a html tag (more specifically ‘h3’). I already tried the “.html()” as this example: [[examples | p5.js]](https://p5js.org/examples/dom-input-and-button.html), but for some reason this doesn’t work in my context. I’ll let my code below:

```
let inputName, bttName, yourName;

function setup() {
let inputDiv = createDiv();
  inputDiv.id("input-section");
  inputDiv.parent("sobre");

  inputName = createInput();
  inputName.addClass("input-name");
  inputName.parent("input-section");

  bttName = createButton('enter');
  bttName.addClass('btt-name');
  bttName.parent("input-section");
  bttName.mousePressed(sendName);

}

function sendName() {
  let userName = inputName.value();
  yourName.html(userName);
}
```

I need this in as a variable, because after I’ll format it inside a div in css. Is there another way to transform this value?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `yourName.html(createElement('h3', userName.value()));` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're wanting to output the name that's entered into a `h3` element?

In that case you could just use:

```
yourName = createElement('h3', userName);
```

like they've done in that reference you linked.

Here's a running example:

```js
let inputName, bttName, yourName;

function setup() {
  let inputDiv = createDiv();
  inputDiv.id("input-section");
  
  inputName = createInput();
  inputName.addClass("input-name");
  inputName.parent("input-section");


   bttName = createButton('enter');
   bttName.addClass('btt-name');
   bttName.parent("input-section");
   bttName.mousePressed(sendName);

}


function sendName() {
  let userName = inputName.value();
  yourName = createElement('h3', userName);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```